# Create XML from multiple CSV's in multiple folders

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xelement

The whole point of what I am doing is I need to create a master XML from multiple CSV files located in multiple subfolders within one master folder.

This is what I am using right now, but it seems to overwrite and creates an xml for only the last CSV...

```
String AudioDir = @"C:\XMLFILES";
        DirectoryInfo AudiodirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(AudioDir);
        if (AudiodirInfo.Exists == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AudioDir);
        }

        List<String> AudioXMLFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\LOGGER AUDIO", "*.csv*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        XElement audxml = null;
        foreach (string file in AudioXMLFiles)
        {
            string[] lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(file);
           audxml = new XElement("root",
           from str in lines2
           let columns = str.Split(',')
           select new XElement("recording_info",
                   new XElement("recorded_accound_id", columns[1]),
                   new XElement("date_created_ts", String.Format("{0:####-##-##  ##:##:##}", Convert.ToInt64(columns[2] + columns[3]))),                                    
                   new XElement("recorded_cid", columns[9]),//1
                   new XElement("recording_tag", columns[1]),
                   new XElement("filename", columns[1] + "_" + columns[2] + "_" + columns[3]),
                   new XElement("record", columns[3]),//Record in TimeoutException format
                   new XElement("from_caller_id", columns[10] + "  <" + columns[8] + ">")



               ));


        }
        audxml.Save(@"C:\XMLFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting audxml in each iteration of the foreach.  What you probably want is to create a root node outside the loop and then add each file's xml output to that root node.

```
XElement audxml = new XElement("root");

foreach (string file in AudioXMLFiles)
    {
        string[] lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(file);
       XElement filexml = new XElement("root",
       from str in lines2
       let columns = str.Split(',')
       select new XElement("recording_info",
               new XElement("recorded_accound_id", columns[1]),
               new XElement("date_created_ts", String.Format("{0:####-##-##  ##:##:##}", Convert.ToInt64(columns[2] + columns[3]))),                                    
               new XElement("recorded_cid", columns[9]),//1
               new XElement("recording_tag", columns[1]),
               new XElement("filename", columns[1] + "_" + columns[2] + "_" + columns[3]),
               new XElement("record", columns[3]),//Record in TimeoutException format
               new XElement("from_caller_id", columns[10] + "  <" + columns[8] + ">")
           ));

           audXml.Add(fileXml);
    }
    audxml.Save(@"C:\XMLFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are recreating the document every iteration of the foreach loop.

Instead you should create the root document before the loop. Then you add elements to the root inside the loop.

Example:

```
XElement audxml = new XElement("root");
foreach(...)
{
  //..
  audxml.Add(new XElement("blabla"));
}
```

This will keep the data in the XElement for each iteration, and just add onto the existing root element.

// Mike